# Users is asked twice same question because of duplicated code

Tags: python, function, input, duplicates

I am trying to create a kind of TV show social media programme to practice and improve my basic coding skills, but I am a bit stuck.

The programme has a menu where shows users what they can do: create a profile, modify the profile, review the profile, updating the profile with a new TV show and leaving the programme.

I created several functions but I reached a point where I cannot move forward. The functions I created are asking the user the same question twice. I do want to avoid that but I am not able to find any solution.

This is what I have got so far:

```
import os

def ask_option():
    # Print menu and return the chosen option
    print("\nMENU\n")
    print("Click 1 to create a user profile.")
    print("Click 2 to modify your user profile.")
    print("Click 3 to review your user profile.")
    print("Click 4 to update your user profile.")
    print("Click 5 to leave the programme.")

    opcion = int(input("\nWhat do you chose?\n"))
    return opcion 

def ask_data():
    # Ask data to user and return 
    name = input("What's your name? ").capitalize()
    surname = input("What's your surname?: ").capitalize()
    year = int(input("When were you born? "))
    age = 2022 - year
    age = str(age)
    favourite_show = input("What's your favourite TV show of all times? ").title()
    show = input("What are you binge watching right now? ").title()
    
    return name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show

def save_data(name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show):
    # Save user's data in a file
    file = open(name + ".user", "w", encoding = "UTF-8") 
    file.write(name+"\n"+surname+"\n"+age+"\n"+favourite_show+"\n"+show+"\n")
    file.close()
    
def print_data(name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show):
    # Print user's data
    profile = name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show
    print("Name:", name, surname)
    print("Age:", age, "years old")
    print("Favourite TV Show:", favourite_show)
    print("Currently binge watching:", show)
    return profile   

def create_profile():
    # Function that calls ask_data(), prints user profile created and calls print_data()
    # Before creating a profile, should check if there is another profile with same user's name. If the user already exists, return a message. If user is new, create profile. 
    # moveforward = True
    # while moveforward:
        # name = input("What's your name? ").capitalize()
        # if not os.path.isfile(name + ".user"): 
            # name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show = ask_data()
            # save_data(name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show)
            # print("\nYour profile has been created.\n")
            # print_data(name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show)
            # moveforward = False
        # else:
            # print("\nThere is already a profile with that user name.")

    name = input("What's your name? ").capitalize()
    if os.path.isfile(name + ".user"):
        print("There is already a profile with that user name.")
        return
        
    name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show = ask_data()
    save_data(name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show)
    print("\nYour profile has been created.\n")
    print_data(name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show)
            
def modificar_perfil():
    (etc, etc)
```

So the thing here is that user's gets asked twice: What's your name inside the create_profile() functions and I do not know how to fix it.

Can anyone share any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the question about their name from `ask_data`, since you ask that in `create_profile`.

Comment: Or remove that question from `create_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for name twice. Once in create profile, when you are checking to see if a profile has been created, and again in the first line of ask_data.

Perhaps move your profile checking logic into ask data.

```
def create_profile():

    # ------ move this logic into ask_data, otherwise, you will ask again when it is called
    name = input("What's your name? ").capitalize() 
    if os.path.isfile(name + ".user"):
        print("There is already a profile with that user name.")
        return
    # --------------------------- 
    
    name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show = ask_data()
    save_data(name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show)
    print("\nYour profile has been created.\n")
    print_data(name, surname, year, age, favourite_show, show)
```